# TestNG Parallel Testing, Opens two browser but runs all tests only in 1 browser

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing, automated-tests, testng

Hi All I have an XML class

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Auto">
        <classes>
            <class name="Auto.....Name_of_class1......"/>
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Bad">
        <classes>
            <class name="Bad.....Name_of_class2......"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
     </suit>
```

When I run this XML file, first it opens two Browsers ( Chrome ) then run both classes. But here is the confusing part for me

When the browsers are open, out of these two browsers, only one browser will test cases.
In my cases, I am running two classes parallel and each class has 2-3 test cases.
but all of the test cases will run in one browser. 2nd browser just open and goes to the bases URL

Also, I have tried changing parallel to "class", "True" but no success.
Results set are also very messy, Please take look at the screenshot

[image]

Both classes calls :-

```
public static WebDriver initDriver() {
    
            if (driver == null) {
    
                switch (prop.getProperty("browser")) {
    
                case "chrome":
                    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
                    break;
    
                case "firefox":    
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver(fOptions);
  
                    break;
    
                default:
                        System.out.println("Wrong driver was chosen!");
    
                }
    
                action = new Actions(driver);
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
            }
            return driver;
    
        }
```

Comment: How is `driver` declared in this class?

Comment: Driver is called from TestBase class,and TestBase class function  initDriver()

TestBase is  extended to testClasses

Comment: No! The line `driver = new ChromeDriver();`, how/where is `driver` declared? Is it `static`?

Comment: Yes, It is Static.

Comment: `public static WebDriver driver;`

Answer (score 2):

This is purely a Java problem and has very little to do with [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) (or [testng](/questions/tagged/testng)).

A `static` field belongs to the class (and not the instance of a class) and so it exists only **once** no matter how many times you call that class. You can read more about this [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/fields.html#static-and-non-static-fields) and many other sources.

As it is, every time your code executes `driver = new ChromeDriver()` (or `driver = new FirefoxDriver()`) it launches a new browser, which you observed, and **overwrites** the field `driver` with the new value.

In order to run your tests in parallel, you **must** make the `driver` not `static`. You will also have to adjust your code to access this field in a non-static way.

Comment: I am not using Selenium Grid and ThreadLocal. is that is causing all issue ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Provide a [mcve] and maybe we can help you.

Comment: I have updated the code with ThreadLocal class but still the same Result. Here is updated code

Comment: I have updated my question here 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65893972/testng-parallel-testing-opens-two-browsers-but-runs-all-tests-only-in-1-browser

Comment: No idea what you are trying to accomplish there. I would start with something like this https://www.toolsqa.com/testng/testng-parallel-execution/ Once that is working for you, then adjust it to your use-case. Good luck!

Comment: It saved my life. I had this working and following a dumb sonarqube suggestion to change driver to protected static, it broke the test paralellism unnoticed...it's a chance God has made people like you, because you really fixed my issues in 20 seconds. Thanks , and please accept 1 bitcoin :) (note : selenium locally, no grid)